# What are some of the best practices while using CFWheels framework?

Tags: cfwheels

Although this is more of general question but it will extremely helpful for newbie like me to get the benefit from more experienced people on stackoverflow. I have read the ColdBox wiki ColdFusion best practices. I have searched same for the CFWheels but couldn't find the same. So I was wondering what are the best practices while using CFWheels framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too broad of a question for StackOverflow, but I can recommend that you watch these screencasts:

- [DBMigrate Create Operations](http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/view/17)
- [ColdRoute Plugin](http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/view/19)
- [Series: Basic CRUD Operations](http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/series/2)

Using DBMigrate to generate your database is a great way for team-based development. And ColdRoute adds so many nice conventions for routing that it affects how I do development in the controller layer in some big ways.